# Get-AzureStorageBlob : Could not get the storage context. Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage context

Tags: powershell, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am using powershell with Azure cmdlets to try and simply see items in blob storage

```
  $StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'myblobname' -StorageAccountKey '2341231234asdff2352354345=='
  $Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'mycontainer' -Context $StorageContext  
  $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container  $Container

Error:
Get-AzureStorageBlob : Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage context.
```

I am 100% sure that the credentials are correct (just random shortened credential data in this post)

Why would I get this error?

Is AzureRM used? The AzureRM  version is listed as 3.8.0.
Which versions of which scripts would I need for this to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would need to include `StorageContext` here as well:

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container  $Container
```

So your code would be:

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $Container -Context $StorageContext
```

Comment: As an "arch" newbie ... I also needed to know a bit more and finally figured it out:

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "theaccountname" -StorageAccountKey = "Key1 or Key2"

And the of course -Context $StorageContext as placed in the cmdlet above.

Comment: It could be `New-AzureStorageContext` or `New-AzStorageContext` depending on the Azure powershell version.

Comment: i use PSVersion "5.1.19041.1645" and New-AzStorageContext is working fine. When I used AzureStorageContext, it was throwing error.